# Custom hash for unique ID

Tags: algorithm, hash, uniqueidentifier, unique-id

I want to do something similar to what YouTube does. For example, this is a valid YouTube video ID  `didzxUkrtS0`

Right now I am storing user's IDs with an integer number, and I want to translate those numbers to a 8 character alphanumerical identification. For example: `FZ3EY1IC` (not hexadecimal)

I already know that I can implement it with MD5 and then take the first 8 hex numbers, but it doesn't cover the entire alphabet.

What should I do to create a unique pattern using integers, that should never repeat?

Comment: Probably this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051949/map-incrementing-integer-range-to-six-digit-base-26-max-but-unpredictably/1052896#1052896

Comment: The thing is that if I use only a one digit number (for example 3), it will translate to `c` instead of 8 alphanumeric characters

Comment: Did you read the answer carefully? Look at the table at the end of the answer, all IDs map to 6-character unique strings

Comment: @Patashu The same as I said before, I want 8 alphanumeric characters. Base64 will give me only a few if I use only one digit

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680176/alphanumeric-hash-a-z-0-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your integer 5 8-bit bytes long (by adding a byte with a random value if your integer is 32-bit), that's 40 bits of data.

Cryptographically encrypt the 5 bytes of your integer using some key, which you probably want to keep private.

Slice the 40 encrypted bits into 8 5-bit parts. Encode each part using 32 alphanumeric characters. You may choose to use different 32 (out of the total 36) characters for each part.

The reverse operation is trivial.

Comment: This idea is perfect. Thanks

Comment: Not perfect, but it'll definitely work and it's easy to implement if you already have cryptographic encryption and decryption routines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what sites like youtube and bitly do is store a big table in the database that translates the alphanumerical identifiers for each link to the internal ID of what they're for (either that or it's stored in the row). And when it needs a new identifier, compute a random one and store it. The reason why you need to do this is so that an attacker cannot predict the ID of the next piece of content to be added.